# building complex html div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a loop that appends divs to an element in my html. In the div that I am appending however, I have an icon embedded in one of the div attributes, and it seems to be causing an issue.I do not know how to handle the syntax of this. As you would expect, the div is not formatted properly when appended and it has a bunch the html printed on it, obviously showing that it's not being processed.

While I would love it if someone knew how to fix the bug here, I would also be open to building the div in an entirely different manor, as, even when less complex, building divs in this format always seems to be trouble. So if anyone has suggestions for a more appropriate method, that would be awesome.

```
 for (i = 0; i < newGroupsLength; i++) {
    var groupDiv= '<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: -4px;">'+
                      '<div class="panel-heading">' +
                         '<h5 class="panel-title">'+
  /*this line is the issue*/   '<input type="checkbox" checked class="switch-demo switch-mini" data-on="success" data-off="danger" data-on-label="<i class="fa fa-check">'+'</i>" data-off-label="<i class="fa fa-remove">'+'</i>" ><a data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">' + newGroups[i].name + '<i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right">'+'</i>'+'<i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right">'+'</i>'+'</a>' +
                         '</h5>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse ">' +
                          '<div class="panel-body">blah blah blah</div>' +
                          '</div>' +
                      '</div>';

     alert(newGroups[i].type);
    $('#groups-container').append(groupDiv);

                            }
```

sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated

Comment: Two words: javascript templates.

Comment: Have you tried coding this in a static page first? If you are dynamically inserting complex `html` into the DOM is easier to have it working before you code the `javascript`.

Comment: You need to escape the inner double quotes, eg here `data-on-label="<i class="fa fa-check">'+'</i>"` should be `data-on-label="<i class=&quot;fa fa-check&quot;>'+'</i>"`.  However I would build this up differently using jQuery an element at a time.

Comment: @charliebrown hey, yeah, I built it html first. worked well there.

Comment: thanks @James Thorpe. Will explore that.

Comment: thanks @Aleksandr M. Will look into those.

Comment: Wow, why are you doing it like this, if you really need to inject div's into the DOM, then you should be looking at client side HTML template solution perhaps something like handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/ or moustache https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ , there are various others, if you really want to get down and dirty with manipulating dom objects client side then you might be better of looking at angular or knockout etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is using double-quote inside double-quoted strings:

```
'data-on-label="<i class="fa fa-check">'+'</i>" data-off-label="<i class="fa fa-remove">'
```

You need to escape any `"` inside the string like this  `\"`

```
'data-on-label="<i class=\"fa fa-check\">'+'</i>" data-off-label="<i class=\"fa fa-remove\">'
```

Your are better off using a template-based solution. Even one as simple as placing the `html` in a dummy script block and referencing the `html()` within it (replacing contents as needed).

Comment: Can you escape double quotes in an attribute like that?  I think in this instance it needs to be `&quot;`?

Comment: @James Thorpe: Yes, you are correct. The whole thing is a little messed up though so not even sure that will help.

Comment: Yeah - templates are definitely the right answer here

Comment: Thanks. As an amateur, I am realizing now this is not the right approach. I will go after the templates.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've never escaped double quotes like that using jQuery and it has always worked for me... because I've always used single quotes for Strings.

Comment: @charliebrownie these are specifically going into an attribute though, and with a mixture of single and double quotes  [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdaofr7b/)

Comment: @JamesThorpe for example:
`'<div class="some_class"></div>'`

Comment: @JamesThorpe oh yeah! I see what you mean now, I was talking about a different thing, you are completely right!